# Why am I required to run npm run watch every time I want to see my JS and SCSS changes?

Tags: javascript, laravel, debugging, webpack

To start off, I run `artis cache:clear && artis config:clear && artis view:clear && artis route:clear && artis clear-compiled && npm run dev && composer dump-autoload` on my command line to compile all assets and begin working but....

I'm facing this weird issue where I need to run `npm run watch` so that my JS and SCSS changes can be reflected every single time.  Is there a way I can not have to do this every time?  FYI, I'm running `npm run watch` inside my Vagrant box while inside my project's directory.  Anyone know a way around this?

Comment: ```npm run watch``` should monitor changes in your files. So after saving new version of file, it should automatically rebuild it.

Comment: @Magiczne yeah I agree but for some reason it's not.  I'm going to try `npm run watch-poll` and see if it makes a difference.

Comment: @Magiczne yep `npm run watch-poll` did the trick!